# Burninate [planning-game]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[planning-game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/planning-game) seems like a very poor tag to me. No tag wiki and 5 questions tagged with this. All of which seem to be about people planning to build a game (except for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838393/do-you-practice-the-planning-game) which is about some sort of development strategy).

All in all, seems like it's pointless. I would go through and remove it myself but didn't want to generate 5 edit suggestions for this.

Opinions?

(Puns are welcome)

Comment: I think [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215856/reinforcement-learning-with-variable-actions) should be tagged with only [tag:planning] -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215856/reinforcement-learning-with-variable-actions

Comment: well there are only 5 questions overall. Wont take long

Comment: @SurajRao I don't have edit permissions, I didn't want to waste people's time by raising edit suggestions for this.

Comment: I removed the fluff; we're down to 2 questions now. Not sure if those questions are on-topic or not, as they're outside of my domain knowledge. Actual questions about [the planning game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_programming_practices#Planning_game) as defined in software development are off-topic for Stack Overflow, so the tag does not need to exist. It doesn't seem like the 2 remaining questions have anything to do with the extreme programming practice, though. They should probably just be retagged.

Comment: @CodyGray I've retagged them with [tag:planning], because they were the case from tag excerpt: "Examples include game-playing AI, industrial automation, turn-by-turn directions, the "A*" algorithm for heuristic search"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was done. I am posting this as answer just for making this accepted by OP (if possible).